# how to get wso2 esb proxy parameter

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

hello i am writing a proxy service in wso2 ESB with MQTT transport i want to access to the parameters how can i retreive those parameters .

here is my code:

-1
                    1
                
                
                    0
                
            
        
        
            
            
            
            
        
        
            
        
        
    
    mqttConFactory
    text/plain
    2
    esb.test1
    false

Comment: <parameter name="mqtt.connection.factory">mqttConFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="mqtt.content.type">text/plain</parameter>
    <parameter name="mqtt.subscription.qos">2</parameter>
    <parameter name="mqtt.topic.name">esb.test1</parameter>
    <parameter name="mqtt.session.clean">false</parameter>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to extract these values from a proxy service parameters. They don't exist in transport, synapse or axis2 scope properties, neither in message context properties set.